# How to prove that chessboard of size $n \times 3$, with even $n$ and $n \geq 10$, has a closed knight's tour with induction?

Tags: induction

I am trying to do an exercise on this topic. I have realized that base cases should be $n = 10$ and $n = 12$. Also I realized that I would need to use $(n+4)\times 3$ during my inductive step. But that is pretty much it. I really don't understand the structure which I am meant to prove this. Or the steps after Any help given would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: these links may be helpful: [link 1](https://oeis.org/A070030), [link 2](http://www.mayhematics.com/t/ob.htm).

Comment: This may be helpful [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69107/how-do-i-prove-that-any-chessboard-of-size-n-times-3-where-n-is-even-and-n?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The key inductive part after setting the base cases for $3\times 10$ and $3\times 12$ boards is to show how to extend a tour on the board that is four squares shorter. This is very straightforward for extending a closed tour, because we know the shape of the path at the end of the board through the corner squares (shown on the left):

[image: path through corner squares]

and we can then break into that path to cover a four-column-longer board as follows:

[image: extended tour]

(where the two solid red links and the whole of the blue path replace the removed dotted red link).