# Freeing the trapped knight

Tags: recreational-mathematics

The trapped knight problem is as follows. Place all natural numbers (starting with 1) in a spiral on an infinite square grid. A knight begins in the cell labeled 1. Each turn it jumps (in an L-shape) to an unvisited cell with the lowest number. It turns out that the knight eventually gets trapped - has nowhere to move. Neil Sloane made a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGQe8waGJ4w) about it.

Maarten Mortier [simulated](https://medium.com/swlh/the-trapped-knight-revisited-132c034a8a28) this game for all knights with movements $(x,y)$ such that $1 \leq x,y \leq 80$ and found that they all get trapped eventually. The knight $(8,71)$ takes the longest to get trapped at $2400005$ steps.

Now I have the following questions:

1. Is there a knight (x,y) that never gets trapped? Assume that $1 \leq x \leq y$.
2. Can we number the infinite grid in a different pattern, such that the standard (1,2) knight does not get trapped?

Comment: Without restrictions on the pattern, 2 seems to be quite easy.  Make a straight line for the knight to travel along with big numbers nearby so the knight follows the desired path.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but I don't know how to formalize such a pattern of numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a dense infinite tour for a standard (1,2) knight: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2837147/207316

Comment: Nice that solves 2 very well.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, the spreadsheet below gives one approach.  I am making a straight path for the knight to follow.  I put 1,2,3 to start the path, then continued with odd numbers.  I put the even numbers starting with 4 clockwise to fill the cells the knight could move to but I don't want it to.[image]